# Issue with AEM AssemblerService - not able to Assemble 2 or more PDF or XDP documents into single file using AEM OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi, aem, blueprint-osgi

> Note: I have installed AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar and `AEM-FORMS-6.4-OSX-5.0.86.zip` installed into it to use AEM forms services and be able to see `AssemblerService` on my path `http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr`

I have tried to assemble 2 PDFs using `com.adobe.fd.assembler.service.AssemblerService` (also tried with XDP) but I’m getting below exceptions.

Here is how I call the `AssemblerService`:

```
AssemblerResult result = assemblerService.invoke(ddxDocument, inputDocuments, assemblerOptionSpec);
```

`ddxDocument` ddxDocument as part of this variable passing below DDX format document:

```
<DDX xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/">
<XDP result="MyXDPResult">
<XDP source="sourceXDP1"/>
<XDP source="sourceXDP2"/>
<XDP source="sourceXDP3"/>
</XDP>
</DDX>
```

`inputDocuments` as part of this variable passing Map with source file name as key and Document as value Object.

Below is the request payload I have used (2 PDF encoded format array)

Exception Log file:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rsa/jsafe/JSAFE_SecureRandom
at com.adobe.internal.pdfm.util.Util.appendRandomNumberToPrefix(Util.java:169) [com.adobe.aemfd.adobe-aemfd-assembler:5.0.36]
at com.adobe.internal.pdfm.logging.JobLog.<init>(JobLog.java:126) [com.adobe.aemfd.adobe-aemfd-assembler:5.0.36]
at com.adobe.internal.pdfm.logging.PDFMLogger.startLog(PDFMLogger.java:457) [com.adobe.aemfd.adobe-aemfd-assembler:5.0.36]
at com.adobe.fd.assembler.service.impl.AssemblerServiceImpl.setupEnvironment(AssemblerServiceImpl.java:1019) [com.adobe.aemfd.adobe-aemfd-assembler:5.0.36]
at com.adobe.fd.assembler.service.impl.AssemblerServiceImpl.invoke(AssemblerServiceImpl.java:227) [com.adobe.aemfd.adobe-aemfd-assembler:5.0.36]
at com.cdk.eforms.osgi.core.servlets.AssemblerServiceServlet.assembleDocuments(AssemblerServiceServlet.java:106) [com.cdkglobal.osgi.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at com.cdk.eforms.osgi.core.servlets.AssemblerServiceServlet.doPost(AssemblerServiceServlet.java:77) [com.cdkglobal.osgi.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:146) [org.apache.sling.api:2.16.4]
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:342) [org.apache.sling.api:2.16.4]
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:374) [org.apache.sling.api:2.16.4]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:156) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageLockFilter.doFilter(PageLockFilter.java:91) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96) [com.day.cq.cq-personalization:5.11.54]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:71) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:126) [com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-ugcbase-impl:2.4.19]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:437) [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-core:5.11.296]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:154) [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-core:5.11.296]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70) [com.adobe.granite.rest.api:1.1.10]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:121) [com.adobe.granite.requests.logging:1.0.20]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96) [com.adobe.granite.rest.assets:1.0.56]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217) [com.adobe.granite.csrf:1.0.18]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:372) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-mobile-core:5.11.10]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.cdk.eforms.osgi.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:50) [com.cdkglobal.osgi.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.cdk.eforms.aem.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:56) [com.cdk.eforms.aem.eforms-aem-lib.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.livecycle.content.appcontext.impl.AppContextFilter.doFilter(AppContextFilter.java:69) [com.adobe.livecycle.content.core-bundle:5.0.24]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.livecycle.dsc.clientsdk.internal.ResourceResolverHolderFilter.doFilter(ResourceResolverHolderFilter.java:37) [com.adobe.livecycle.dsc.clientsdk:3.0.4]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91) [com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:1.9.47]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.11.46]
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.11.46]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76) [com.adobe.granite.optout:1.0.0]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.11.46]
at com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet.doFilter(CoreFormHandlingServlet.java:126) [com.adobe.cq.core.wcm.components.core:2.0.4]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.fd.core.security.internal.CurrentUserServiceImpl.doFilter(CurrentUserServiceImpl.java:114) [adobe-aemfd-core-security:2.0.6]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.11.218]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122) [com.adobe.cq.cq-history:5.10.6]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100) [com.day.cq.mcm.cq-mcm-campaign:1.3.8]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:87) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81) [com.adobe.granite.httpcache.core:1.0.8]
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60) [com.adobe.granite.httpcache.core:1.0.8]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.10]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152) [org.apache.sling.security:1.1.10]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83) [com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper:1.0.4]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:234) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:120) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:328) [org.apache.sling.security:1.1.10]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308) [com.adobe.granite.license:1.2.6.CQ640-B0001]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96) [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter:1.2.4]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.10]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116) [org.apache.sling.featureflags:1.2.2]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.doFilter(RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.java:63) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:147) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1000) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:584) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:3.4.7.B012]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
26.06.2018 19:36:57.462 *WARN* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1530022017452] POST /services/assembleDocuments HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.components.ComponentCacheImpl Requested Path /services/assembleDocuments.servlet is not in available search paths
26.06.2018 19:43:59.275 *WARN* [sling-oak-observation-15] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.RefreshStrategy This session has been idle for 8 minutes and might be out of date. Consider using a fresh session or explicitly refresh the session.
```

Comment: see this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2422490

Answer (score 1):

> The log tells you that you are missing the RSA library (class `com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SecureRandom`)

You need to configure the Document Service as outlined in adobe documentation here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6/configuring-document-services.html

and provide that library to the boot delegation.

The same document above has instructions about the `AssemblerService` dependencies and how to insure they are running.

> Also see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2422490

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Musallam , after following likes which you shared, exception got resoled, but now i'm getting below exception while calling AssemblerService, Could you please help me on this.
 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while merging documents for preview - AEM-ASM-S00-002: Failed to execute the DDX - error messages provided.

at com.cdk.eforms.osgi.core.servlets.AssemblerServiceServlet.assembleDocuments(AssemblerServ iceServlet.java:130)

Comment: that's a different issue, possibly with your PDF's but out of your question's scope. Please create a new question for that. If this answer helped fix your original question, feel free to accept it.